# Cannot resolve DNS address with CFHostStartInfoResolution if not on main queue

Tags: ios, core-foundation

I have a project that is using the SimplePing example source code.  It works perfectly fine much of the time, but I have run into a situation where asynchronous name name resolution  never executes the callback.

The code that kicks off the DNS lookup (directly from SimplePing.m) looks like this:

```
    CFHostClientContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFStreamError       streamError;

    assert(self->_host == NULL);

    self->_host = CFHostCreateWithName(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) self.hostName);
    assert(self->_host != NULL);

    CFHostSetClient(self->_host, HostResolveCallback, &context);

    CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(self->_host, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    NSLog(@">CFHostStartInfoResolution");
    success = CFHostStartInfoResolution(self->_host, kCFHostAddresses, &streamError);
    NSLog(@"<CFHostStartInfoResolution");
```

This normally works fine.  But I ran into a problem where the name would never resolve under some circumstances.  After much digging, it appears that any time the code is not running on the main queue, the callback will never be invoked.  Is that to be expected?  In this same circumstance (i.e. not on the main queue) I also noticed that a timer I setup never fired.

Since the documentation makes no mention of this restriction and there is actually a function CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop() which allows me to specify the run loop, I find it hard to believe that I am restricted to using the main queue.

I feel that I might be missing something fundamental here.  If anybody can help me understand what is happening, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If the method runs on another runloop, you should make sure that runloop is still running or running on kCFRunLoopDefaultMode when DNS finished.

Comment: The trouble is that DNS never finishes because it seems that the runloop stops running.  At least that's what I think is happening.  I don't really understand what causes a runloop to stop running.

Comment: I had a similar situation and it turned out that my problem was having a local variable rather than a property on my UIViewController. The variable was being released too early and the code never got past the second NSLog shown above.

Comment: like @KudoCC mentioned: Make sure your Runloop's `mode` matches the `mode` you're using for `CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop`